# How to do a search with multiple non-obligatory Input fields?

Tags: abap

I would like to ask how to do a basic search filtering in a selection screen that has multiple input fields which aren't required.

I tried to do it by using multiple IF statements followed by WHERE clauses which solves my current problem but its not fully correct, if i work with only a few inputs (2 at the moment, 'ID' and 'Number'), the code isn't too long, but if its over 10 or so it feel wrong to do it this way

What i tried so far was approximately like this :

```
IF lv_id IS INITIAL and lv_nr IS INITIAL.

     SELECT * from DBase INTO TABLE Local_Table.

ELSEIF lv_id IS NOT INITIAL AND lv_nr IS INITIAL.

     SELECT * from DBase INTO TABLE Local_Table WHERE ID = lv_nr.

ELSEIF lv_id IS INITIAL AND lv_nr IS NOT INITIAL.

     SELECT * from DBase INTO TABLE Local_Table WHERE Number = lv_nr.

ELSEIF lv_id IS NOT INITIAL AND lv_nr IS NOT INITIAL.

     SELECT * from DBase INTO TABLE Local_Table WHERE ID = lv_id AND Number = lv_nr.
```

The expected result is for the search to get executed correctly by having no input or multiple non-obligatory inputs, without having to write a very long code in case the number of inputs is high.

Answer (score 3):

you can use the IN Operator in your WHERE clause when you have multiple conditions.

First You need to define a Selection Table for every parameter and have to fill them or leave them empty.

```
types: begin of myselopt ,
       sign type char1 ,
       option type char2 ,
       low type ... (depends on the type you want select)
       high type ... ,
    end of myselopt .

types : t_selopt type table of myselopt .   

data: gt_selopt type t_selopt ,
      gt_selopt_2 type t_selopt_2 . #needs to be defined first 

if lv_id is not initial .
    insert value #( sign = 'I' option = 'EQ' low = lv_id ) into table gt_selopt .
endif . 

if lv_nr is not initial .
    insert value #( sign = 'I' option = 'EQ' low = lv_nr ) into table gt_selopt_2 .
endif .
```

You have to do this for every Parameter you want to query. And your query would look like this

```
select * from dbaste into table local_table where id in gt_selopt
                                        and number in gt_selopt_2 .
```

Comment: It could be a little bit shorter with `DATA range_ids LIKE RANGE OF lv_id. range_ids = COND #( WHEN lv_id IS NOT INITIAL THEN VALUE #( ( sign = 'I' option = 'EQ' low = lv_id ) ).`

Answer (score 1):

You can define your input fields as `SELECT-OPTIONS` (with optional `NO INTERVALS NO-EXTENSION` to mimick the look of `PARAMETERS`). Then just use the `IN` operator in your `WHERE` clause:

```
REPORT.

DATA: your_ztable TYPE your_ztable.

SELECT-OPTIONS: s_id FOR your_ztable-id     NO INTERVALS NO-EXTENSION,
                s_nr FOR your_ztable-number NO INTERVALS NO-EXTENSION.

AT SELECTION-SCREEN.

  SELECT * FROM your_ztable
    WHERE id   IN @s_id
    AND number IN @s_nr
    INTO TABLE @DATA(local_table).
```

Answer (score 0):

What about this approach with concatenated where conditions?

```
DATA:
  lv_where TYPE string.


IF lv_id IS NOT INITIAL.
    CONCATENATE ' AND ID' space '=' space '"' lv_id '"' INTO lv_where.
ENDIF. 

IF lv_nr IS NOT INITIAL.
    CONCATENATE ' AND Number' space '=' space '"' lv_nr '"' INTO lv_where.
ENDIF.

IF lv_where IS NOT INITIAL.
    SHIFT lv_where By 5 PLACES. " to remove leading _AND_ (
ENDIF.

SELECT * from DBase INTO TABLE Local_Table WHERE (lv_where).
```

Comment: I am sorry i do not understand how that approach would make the code shorter if i had 10+ input fields?

Comment: @Mick you do not required to have all variants of combinations between your input fileds.
You cannot do code short because in any scenario you have to write SQL query with 10+ conditions in the worst case and somehow you have to define this complex query.
If you take a look on other replies then you'll see that in any case you will go with multiple IFs or with an Where clause that contains all your columns with defined SELECT-OPTIONS for example

Comment: @Mick, support Sergey. Dynamic query could be your only option if you have some contradictory search criteria, which intersect between each other or influence each other. Seltabs with IN statements fit most but not all cases